# MS-Access (SQL): Strange behaviour of the MID() function when using decimal arguments

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have noticed strange behavior of the MID() function in MS Access when used in combination with decimal numbers as arguments.

The data is as follows:

```
table: Test 

ID  Name    Surname 
1   Jamal   Winstone 
2   Joe     Roan 
3   Jake    Tumble 
4   Lea     More
```

The SQL statement is:

```
SELECT MID(Surname, ID, LEN(Name)/2) FROM Test
```

The results are:

```
Expr1000 

Wi 
oa 
mb 
e
```

However, shouldn't it be as follows?

```
MID(Winstone, 1, LEN(Jamal)/2) = MID(Winstone, 1, 5/2) = MID(Winstone, 1, 2.5) = Wi (only 2 characters)
MID(Roan, 2, LEN(Joe)/2) = MID(Roan, 2, 3/2) = MID(Roan, 2, 1.5) = o (only 1 character)
MID(Tumble, 3, LEN(Jake)/2) = MID(Tumble, 3, 4/2) = MID(Tumble, 3, 2) = mb (2 charactes)
MID(More, 4, LEN(Lea)/2) = MID(More, 4, 3/2) = MID(More, 4, 1.5) = e (only 1 character)
```

This is very strange. Any ideas why this is happening, are the numbers with decimal places rounded?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do here (it looks very strange), but it will soon fail when ID gets larger than Surname length.

Comment: Here is the spec for the MID() function https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/mid-function-427e6895-822c-44ee-b34a-564a28f2532c

Answer (score 1):

The logic here is very simple:

Mid takes a `Long`, so needs to cast a float/decimal/currency to a `Long` first.

Casting to a long uses banker's rounding (to the nearest even) on halves (`Clng(1.5)` = `Clng(2.5)` = 2), see the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/type-conversion-functions).

So these results are entirely expected.

Use `Int` if you want the integer part (e.g. `Int(1.99)` = 1)

Comment: Oh wow, thanks a ton. I didn't know about banker's rounding algorithm. Now everything makes perfectly sense.